# Generic way to deal with typed arrays

Tags: typescript

I want to make a library that deal with typed array but I cannot find in the docs nor in source a generic representation for this. In fact, after lurking in the lib source code I noticed that there is a lot of copy paste between the definitions of this typed arrays:

```
interface Uint32Array {}
interface Float32Array {}
interface Float64Array {}
...
```

They all look the same. So why can this don't come as a generic type of:

```
TypedArray<T>
```

or something alike?

Comment: Are you asking why there's redundancy in the `lib.d.ts` with the definitions for the typed arrays?

Comment: One question lid to the other I think. Both are analogous to each other.

Comment: My guess is that because they all extend `TypedArray` (check the `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Uint32Array())`) which seems to be native. If you try to use this `TypedArray` you'll get `"Uncaught ReferenceError: TypedArray is not defined"`. The definitions in the `lib.d.ts` don't use it because it something "under the hood". Again, this is a guess only.